# How to create a dynamic SRC URL using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Backstory:

We are an affiliate merchant and received a tracking code to implement on the heading page of our sales page. However the tracking code requires the amount and the order ID to be filled dynamically.

Our current platform doesn't provide liquid fields to assign in the tracking code, so I had to figure out what fields exists and how to get them to propagate the SRC url which is the tracking code.

Using Zapier I was able to pull the key fields that provide the information we need:

```
subscription_id:    sub_AIhebhUVf1aV4z - The Tracking ID
contact__contact_profile__known_ltv:    7.95 - The amount
```

I'm not sure what code Zapier is using to pull this information, I'm assuming it's a GET. You can set these fields as InputData and recall the information into Javascript but I am not having any luck putting the script together.

Input Data

amount = contact__contact_profile__known_ltv

tracking = subscription_id

```
var pixel ='<img ' + 'src="https://shareasale.com/sale.' + 
'cfm?amount='+ inputData.amount + '&tracking=' +
inputData.tracking + '&transtype=SALE&' + 
'merchantID=XXXX"'+ 
' width="1" height="1">';
document.write(pixel);
```

Anyone have an idea why this code doesn't work and how to make it run? much appreciated.

the tracking code provided by the affiliate is:

```
<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=AMOUNT&tracking=SUBSCRIPTION_ID&transtype=SALE&merchantID=XXXX" width="1" height="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in combining vars but I think it is not working because  you are only creating a string, not an image. instead try below

```
var pixel ='https://shareasale.com/sale.' + 
'cfm?amount='+ inputData.amount + '&tracking=' +
inputData.tracking + '&transtype=SALE&' + 
'merchantID=XXXX"';

var img = new Image;
img.src = pixel;
img.height = 1;
img.width = 1;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```